# Adobe Illustrator script to delete paths with no stroke

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script in Illustrator that will delete all paths with no strokes on them. When I load this script I get back:

Error 1302 - No such element
Line 7:
-> if( !curPath.stroked)

```
    if( !app.documents.length ) return;
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var paths = doc.pathItems;
    for( var i = paths.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        var curPath = paths;
        if( !curPath.stroked )
            curPath.remove();

   }

}

RemoveNoStrokePaths();
```

Comment: Java and Javascript aren't the same thing. Please [edit] your question and tag it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple typo.

```
var curPath = paths;
```

should be

```
var curPath = paths[i];
```

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you sir!